# datefmt error in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date

I am trying to add a date to an input but seem to be having real problems with the errors even tho the date is displaying

Formatt code

```
    $scope.formatt=function(dte){

return moment(dte).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

}

Html Code:

```
<input id="userName" value="{{formatt(contents.PaymentDate)}}" ng-model="contents.PaymentDate" name="username" type="date" class="form-control">
```

Error:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-03-21%2000%3A00%3A00
at angular.js:38
at Array.<anonymous> (angular.js:22838)
at angular.js:26467
at m.$digest (angular.js:16655)
at m.$apply (angular.js:16928)
at g (angular.js:11266)
at t (angular.js:11464)
at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (angular.js:11405)
```

It is displaying the date fine but i am still getting the errors, any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Are you by any chance getting the data asynchronously? That means at first the value will be null so it will throw errors. After it is retrieved it will succesfully parse it to a date.

Comment: Actually `ngModel` expect `contents.PaymentDate` to be a date as you can see on the error url given on your question [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-03-21%2000:00:00](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-03-21%2000:00:00)

Comment: Yes i am getting the data asynchronously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is coming because ng-model is not able to detect Date object. so convert contents.PaymentDate to date object like as

Controller.js

```
$scope.contents.PaymentDate = new Date($scope.contents.PaymentDate);
```

Comment: Hi i understand this is the problem but im getting 'paymentdate' is undefined

Comment: can you let me know the paymentDate coming from any api request or you just set as new variable.